# php mysql select order details when parent order's value = 1

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'd like to calculate total commission in `order details` when parent `order`'s field `payment_status=1`, it means if order gets paid, then calculate, otherwise ignore it.

The following code is not working, but for your reference.

```
$totalCommissionSql ＝ mysql_query("
    SELECT SUM(a.agent_commission) AS total_commission, a.order_id, b.order_id, b.payment_status 
    FROM order_details a, order b
    WHERE a.order_id=b.order_id AND b.payment_status=1
");

$totalCommissionRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($totalCommissionSql); 

$totalCommission = $totalCommissionRow['total_commission'];
```

i'm not familiar with mysql so looking for help! THANKS !!!

Comment: what is the error was produced?

Comment: Where's your `group by` clause?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy , no error

Comment: @Timekiller , group by? i don't know how to use it..

Comment: Then you should provide table structure, example data and expected results, since it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. Also, if you're not familiar with mysql, test your query in SQL worksheet first, in phpmyadmin or any other sql IDE - it's harder to debug queries when they are already embedded in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(a.agent_commission) AS total_commission,
       a.order_id,
       b.order_id,
       b.payment_status
FROM order_details AS a INNER JOIN `order` AS b USING(order_id)
WHERE b.payment_status = 1;
```

Selecting *a.order_id* and *b.order_id* is unnecessary, both have the same value. Mind the keywords like *order*, you have to treat with care. See more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html